# How to build a array that contains a folder structure?

Tags: php, json

I want to build a Json output to list folder structure inside ExtJS tree panel. The structure should be the equivalent of this array in Json:

```
Array
(
    [text] => .
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => files
                    [children] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => folder 1
                    [children] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [text] => New directory
                    [children] => array(
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => sub_1
                                [children] => array(
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => sub_1_1
                                            [children] => 
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => sub_1_2
                                            [children] => 
                                        )                                    
                                )
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => sub_2
                                [children] => 
                            )                             
                    )
                )    
        )    
)
```

i made this function which shows the structure by going through PHP Manual and examples

```
listFolders('../file_uploads/');
function listFolders($dir){
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($dh as $folder){
        if($folder != '.' && $folder != '..')
        {
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$folder)){
                echo '<li>'.$folder.'</li>';
                listFolders($dir.'/'.$folder);
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

this outputs the structure

- New directory
  - sub_1
    - sub_1_1
      - sub_1_1_1
    - sub_1_2
  - sub_2
- files
- folder 1

I want to know how to convert this output to a array (or the Json) like above?

**solution**

```
print "<pre>";
print_r(listFolders('../file_uploads/'));

function listFolders($dir)
{
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    $return = array();

    foreach ($dh as $folder) {
        if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $folder)) {
                $return[] = array(
                    'text' => $folder,
                    'children' => listFolders($dir . '/' . $folder)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need it in an array?

Comment: i want to build a json output to list folder structure inside a extjs tree panel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function listFolders($dir)
{
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    $return = array();

    foreach ($dh as $folder) {
        if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $folder)) {
                $return[] = array($folder => listFolders($dir . '/' . $folder));
            } else {
                $return[] = $folder;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Seems to work for me, not tested properly though.

Comment: Thanks, this creates the nested array but any idea how to get the key value pair with this function like the array i posted?

Comment: played with this function for while and figured how to get exact out put i need. thanks

Comment: @VladPreda Any offer how to get same result with Iterator Class? Thanks for any assist on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121723/multidimensional-directory-list-with-recursive-iterator

Comment: @YahyaE: answered your question

Comment: @VladPreda Checking right away, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First create an array. For each founded dir, use array_push to the array?

Also take a look at the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php .

Comment: hardly an answer. can you improve by showing the OP some code samples? How will this create a nested array?

Comment: tried that but no idea how to push sub directories into relevant main directories

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$array_folders  = listFolders('../file_uploads/');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_folders);

function listFolders($dir){
    global $ret_array;
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    foreach($dh as $folder){
        if($folder != '.' && $folder != '..')
        {
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$folder)){
                $ret_array[$dir][]  = $folder;
                listFolders($dir.'/'.$folder);
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret_array;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a recursive directory listing. Use below code I hope it should help you. It works for me.

```
<?php
/**
 * Function for recursive directory file list search as an array.
 *
 * @param mixed $dir Main Directory Path.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $fileInfo     = scandir($dir);
    $allFileLists = [];

    foreach ($fileInfo as $folder) {
        if ($folder !== '.' && $folder !== '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder) === true) {
                $allFileLists[$folder . '/'] = listFolderFiles($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder);
            } else {
                $allFileLists[$folder] = $folder;
            }
        }
    }

    return $allFileLists;
}//end listFolderFiles()


$dir = listFolderFiles('your searching directory path ex:-F:\xampp\htdocs\abc');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dir);
echo '</pre>'

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact same result you can, follow bellow code

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    //if (count($ffs) < 1)
    //    return;


    $dirStrArr = array();
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
            $dirStrArr[]=array('parent' => $ff, 'children' => listFolderFiles($dir . '/' . $ff));
        }else{
            $dirStrArr[]=$ff;
        }
    }
    return $dirStrArr;
}
```

Or to get the folder name as index and the child details in the array of the index, you can follow the bellow code

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    //if (count($ffs) < 1)
    //    return;


    $dirStrArr = array();
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
            $dirStrArr[$ff]=listFolderFiles($dir . '/' . $ff);
        }else{
            $dirStrArr[]=$ff;
        }
    }
    return $dirStrArr;
}
```