# Multidimensional Directory List with Recursive iterator

Tags: php, file, recursion, multidimensional-array, iterator

I am trying to get multi-dimensional array for directories formatted as below :

```
[
    {
        "text": "another_folder",
        "href": "gui\/default\/uploads\/another_folder",
        "depth": 0
    },
    {
        "text": "subfold",
        "href": "gui\/default\/uploads\/subfold",
        "depth": 0,
        "nodes": {
                   "text": "sub-subfold",
                   "href": "gui\/default\/uploads\/subfold\/sub-subfold",
                   "depth": 1,
                  }
    }
]
```

I want to use RecursiveIterators. What I have done so far is I am getting all directories listed in given path. I need to go inside to children which is where I stacked.

```
public function list_folders($folder_path='') {

    if(!$folder_path) $folder_path = $this->upl_path;

    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder_path),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $r = array();
    $counter = 0
    foreach ($iterator as $splFileInfo) {
      if($splFileInfo->isDir()) {
        $r[$counter] = array(
          'text' => $splFileInfo->getFilename(),
          'href' => str_replace('\\','/',$splFileInfo->getPathname())
        );
        if(How to check if it has children) {
          $result[$counter] += array('nodes'=> CALL RECURSIVE HERE ? );
      }
      $counter++;
    }


    echo json_encode($r,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

I'd use any idea or help gladly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was almost functional, but it was missing a few key points. I adapted your code so that it works, and added some comments that I hope will help you understand what you were missing:

```
class FolderListing
{

    public function list_folders($folder_path = '', $depth = 0)
    {

        if (!$folder_path) $folder_path = $this->upl_path;

        $iterator = new IteratorIterator(new DirectoryIterator($folder_path));

        $r = array();
        foreach ($iterator as $splFileInfo) {

            if ($splFileInfo->isDot()) {
                continue;
            }

            // we need to do this for both folders and files
            $info = array(
                'text' => $splFileInfo->getFilename(),
                'href' => str_replace('\\', '/', $splFileInfo->getPathname()),
                'depth' => $depth
            );

            // is we have a directory, try and get its children
            if ($splFileInfo->isDir()) {
                // !!! I recommend to do an echo $splFileInfo->getPathname() here
                // to see the order in which recursion works !!!
                $nodes = $this->list_folders($splFileInfo->getPathname(), $depth + 1);

                // only add the nodes if we have some
                if (!empty($nodes)) {
                    $info['nodes'] = $nodes;
                }
            }
            // add the info to the array. No need for a counter :)
            $r[] = $info;
        }

        // the return is important to be able to build the multi dimensional array
        return $r;
    }
}

$test = new FolderListing();
$ret = $test->list_folders('./test'); // change this to whatever you want
var_dump($ret);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you so much fy reply. One loose-end stands. It creates multidimensional array correctly but for example sub-sub-folder display twice.. First it correctly positioned in correct level of array. Second is in the parent level at the end. How we can tell the script, "we used it, remove it from your monitor?"

Comment: Here is the json output. After line:49, it is repetitive. http://pastebin.com/xiERcQBY

Comment: ah, of course :) It's because a recursive iterator was already used, and I was running it again for every subfolder. So I stopped using RecursiveDirectoryIterator and no more duplicates exist, will also try and make a version with RecursiveIterator to see how it works. Coming soon :)

Comment: Updated the code by the way, working properly now with `new IteratorIterator(new DirectoryIterator($folder_path));`

Comment: Working properly now, thank you fy help. I went this way to avoid system load and poor process time of `scandir()` function. As I understand no chance with RecursiveIterator, correct?

Comment: There should be quite good chances with `RecursiveIterator`, and I'll try to do it when I have some time :)